# Create a schema for each user in a group

Tags: postgresql, schema, automation

I'm trying to find a way to create a schema within a database, for each user in a group...

The goal is to automatize the creation process for a structure in a school.

Say, each class is a database, and each student in that class would have a schema to work in. But how can I create a schema for every student automatically?

Thank you for any direction or help you can give me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have created all the users, this can easily be done with some SQL scripting.

The most simple approach is to run a SQL statement that generates the needed CREATE SCHEMA statements and run the result of that (e.g. using psql's `\gexec`  command:

```
select format('create schema %I authorization %I;', usename , usename)
from pg_user;
```

Alternatively you can use a PL/pgSQL block that does everything:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_rec in select usename from pg_user loop
    l_sql := format('create schema %I authorization %I', 
                    l_rec.usename, l_rec.usename);
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

Use a WHERE clause in the SELECT to limit the users to those that are relevant to the current database.

You need to connect to each database and run the statements